# Using a Custom-Defined Comparator in a Constructor

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I'm having difficulty using Comparators in Constructors. When I try the following code:

```
InsertionSorter is = new InsertionSorter(bookList.toArray(new Comparable[bookList.size()]), new GenreComparator(), SortType.ASC);
```

I get this error:

```
no suitable constructor found for InsertionSorter(java.lang.Comparable[],sort.GenreComparator,sort.SortType)
constructor sort.InsertionSorter.InsertionSorter(java.lang.Comparable[],java.util.Comparator<java.lang.Object>,sort.SortType) is not applicable
  (actual argument sort.GenreComparator cannot be converted to java.util.Comparator<java.lang.Object> by method invocation conversion)
constructor sort.InsertionSorter.InsertionSorter(java.lang.Comparable[],sort.SortType) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Here are the useful code snippets:

AbstractSorter.java:

```
abstract class AbstractSorter {
    protected Comparable[] values;
    protected Comparator<Object> cmp;
    protected SortType st;

    protected abstract void doSort();
    protected AbstractSorter(Comparable[] init, SortType type) {
        values = new Comparable[init.length];
        System.arraycopy(init, 0, values, 0, init.length);
        cmp = null;
        st = type;
    }
    protected AbstractSorter(Comparable[] init, Comparator<Object> comp, SortType type) {
        values = new Comparable[init.length];
        System.arraycopy(init, 0, values, 0, init.length);
        cmp = comp;
        st = type;
    }

    public Comparable[] getValues() {
        return values;
    }
}

class InsertionSorter extends AbstractSorter {

    public InsertionSorter(Comparable[] init, SortType type) {
        super(init, type);
    }

    public InsertionSorter(Comparable[] init, Comparator<Object> comp, SortType type) {
        super(init, comp, type);
    }

    @Override
    public void doSort() {
        // sorts values
    }
}

enum SortType {ASC, DSC};
```

Book.java:

```
public class Book implements Cloneable, Comparable<Book> {
    private Person author; // implementation details of Person don't matter here
    private String title, isbn;
    private int year;
    private BookGenre genre;

    public Book(Person authorInit, String titleInit, String isbnInit, 
            int yearInit, BookGenre genreInit) {
        author = authorInit;
        title = titleInit;
        isbn = isbnInit;
        year = yearInit;
        genre = genreInit;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return author.toString() + " " + title + " " + isbn + " " + year 
                + " " + genre;
    }

    @Override
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Book other) {
        return author.compareTo(other.author);
    }

    public Person getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public BookGenre getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }
}

class TitleComparator implements Comparator<Book> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Book a, Book b) {
        return a.getTitle().compareToIgnoreCase(b.getTitle());
    }
}

class GenreComparator implements Comparator<Book> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Book a, Book b) {
        return a.getGenre().compareTo(b.getGenre());
    }
}

enum BookGenre { COMIC, MYSTERY, SCIENCE, TRAVEL };
```

**EDIT** Thanks to Rohit for a solution to this problem, but now I'm having a related problem. In the method `doSort()`, I have the code snippet

```
cmp.compare(values[j-1], values[j])
```

(don't worry, I have checks in place to make sure this isn't called if `cmp == null`. This gives the following error:

```
method compare in interface java.util.Comparator<T> cannot be applied to given types;
  required: capture#1 of ? extends java.lang.Object,capture#1 of ? extends java.lang.Object
  found: java.lang.Comparable,java.lang.Comparable
  reason: actual argument java.lang.Comparable cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? extends java.lang.Object by method invocation conversion
```

Note that I have changed the above in AbstractSort.java to replace `Comparable<Object>` with `Comparable<? extends Object>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GenreComparator` class implements `Comparator<Book>`. So you can't pass an instance of that class where a `Comparator<Object>` is required. Both are non-compatible.

You can however change `Comparator<Object>` to `Comparator<? extends Object>` in your constructor, and also the type of field `cmp` in `AbstractSorter` class.

Comment: Okay, that solved my original problem, but now I'm getting something different when I try to use it in the `doSort()` method. I'll make an edit to the original post so that it's actually legible

Comment: @whyles You would be better off with making the `doSort()` method generic.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help! I made `doSort()` generic (which required some casting within the method to straighten out all of the types), and now everything is flowing nicely